# android с установкой цветов проблема

Tags: android, color

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDataMatrix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



        </LinearLayout>
```

```
        colorName3 =Color.WHITE;
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutImage);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(colorName3);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 700, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//RGBA_F16
        bitmap.eraseColor(colorName3);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        try {
            barcode.drawBarcode(canvas, bounds);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

в эмуляторе все прекрасно, фот картинки и фон слоя белого цвета, но если пробую запустить приложение на телефоне, то фон картинки белый, а фон слоя темный, чуть светлее черного!
Как сделать фон слоя (то что не занято картинкой) тоже белого цвета?

Answer (score 0):

временно сделал костыль, разрешение bitmap сделал размером с экран. но это же дичь

```
 //разрешение экрана
        Display display1 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display1.getRealSize(size);
        int scrWidth = size.x;
        //int scrHeight = size.y;
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrWidth, 700, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//RGBA_F16
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).